# Google Font Family wont change

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm just getting back into webdev as I want to make a simple web page. I'm starting with Bootstrap and building my page around that. I want to be able to change the font family of my header but it's not working. Code below.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  

<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>BOOST YOUR CONFIDENCE</title>
```

```
<section class="sectionone">

    <h1 class="display-1">Confidence Boost</h1>

</section>

<section class="sectiontwo">

    <h2 class="display-4">
        We all need a confidence boost sometimes, click below!
    </h2>

</section>
```

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this website so i'm just working out how to use it. I can't post my CSS but here it is,                                                                                                                  

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

display-1 {
    font-family: 'Chewy', cursive;
}

Comment: where is that style placed? You aren't referencing another stylesheet in this code?

Comment: Oh dear! Haha, i think you're right, i haven't linked my CSS

Comment: Make sure you link it under your bootstrap stylesheet link, then it should work fine.

Comment: Like this?

<link href="Vendors/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Vendors/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Posted how it should look in an answer for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as discussed in the comments, you need to reference your custom style sheet. Make sure it falls after bootstrap so it overrides correctly.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="Vendors/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>BOOST YOUR CONFIDENCE</title>
```

And as pointed out above, make sure your class in your stylesheet starts with a dot.

Comment: Yes i think it does thanks! I'm using Amatic SC from google, which comes with fontweight 700, but it doesn't seem to change anything, i'm using font-weight: 700; in my css.

Comment: Also,

I can't seem to format (add margins/padding) to my sectionone section

Comment: You got a link to what you're working on? Might be easier for me to see whats happening by looking at the page.  Looking at it, the only font you have from Google is Chewy.

Comment: I've actually fixed it! haha. It was because bootstrap was overriding my h1. I had to define it so i changed it to .sectionone h1 {} And that changed the font weight.

Comment: Excellent! glad you're sorted.  If I answered your question you can make it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS works fine for me; the only thing I noticed is that you missed the "." class identifier in the name of the css class, like so:

```
.display-1 {
    font-family: 'Chewy', cursive;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/w4z1fqpz/